# SSRS Looking up data with 2 conditions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Hello please can anyone assist

I have 2 datasets, one of them is filtered to bring back a set of numbers.

I have another dataset using the same data source which is filtered to bring back a different set of numbers.

I want to look up from one dataset to the other to have both sets of figures in the same matrix.

The Matrix is setup to have a name in a row, and month date in the colum.

I want to therefore look up the name from the 2nd dataset as well as the month number and return the value into the above.

Is there anyway to lookup against 2 conditions and return the value ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try joining the two datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can combine the fields into one using a separator between the fields.

```
=Lookup(Fields!MonthNum.Value & "|" & Fields!aName.Value, 
        Fields!MonthNum.Value & "|" & Fields!aName.Value,  
        Fields!Number.Value, "Product")
```

The separator is used to keep values from the first field affecting values from the second.

### Update:

For your issue when there is no month, you can try excluding them:

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!MonthNum.Value), NOTHING, 
Lookup(Fields!MonthNum.Value & "|" & Fields!aName.Value, 
        Fields!MonthNum.Value & "|" & Fields!aName.Value,  
        Fields!Number.Value, "Product")  )
```

If **MonthNum** is **NULL**, it will return NULL (**Nothing** in SSRS).

Comment: Hello thanks, that works perfectly. I have unfiltered both datasets to make sure they are pulling the same data which they are. The problem now is where the normal dataset has no value data for a month, the expression with the lookup is adding in a value which is repeated across all months ! Any ideas ?